# Foreign key referencing the same table... Can you help explain this example?

Tags: database, database-design

If I have a table "users" for a dating website, can the relationship column be a foreign key to another user's primary key within the same table??  It's a 1 to 1 relationship (each person can only have one relationship partner).  Can the value be null (the person is not currently in a relationship)?

What is the correct way to do this in database design?

Comment: The way you have described is the correct way to do it; except you would not call it a _foreign key_ because [a] its not foreign and [b] its not a key. Its just a column that happens to hold the same value as the primary key. Why are you doubting it? Did you implement it and then run into a problem?

Comment: your example is not clear. can you add a pictorial representation

Comment: I'm just not sure if it would be more appropriate to have a separate "relationships" table?  I haven't implemented anything but I want to fully understand design concepts.  I just need expert advise

Comment: I created a picture but I figured out I can't post it (I need 10 reputation)... any other ideas?

Comment: In self referential one to one is not possible.e.g. A primary key can exist in more than one foreign key.

Comment: picture:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DiJO9EqjurNV9fMlY5c01yUWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You'll probably need to enforce this with triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however you will not be able to enforce both people are linked to each other by constraint.  You'll have to ensure that this is the case within your code.

```
UserA has relationship with UserB
UserB has relationship with UserA

UserA has relationship with UserB
UserB has no relationship 

UserA has no relationship
UserB has relationship with UserA
```

All of these are valid FKs for the field and in fact...

```
UserA has relationship with UserB
UserB has relationship with UserC

UserA has relationship with UserB
UserC has relationship with UserB
```

is also allowed by the FK.  You would need to ensure both are set properly in code and proper transactioning around the updates.

You could also make the relationship user unique, this would At least prevent the last case.

Comment: oh okay!  Thanks!  is there a better design method then??

Comment: Not that I can think of.  You can make sure when you update their relationship status, that you do it in a single transaction so it is all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything you want in a table. You give a statement/meaning and the rows that make it true go in the table. A query has a meaning that its rows make true per its tables' meanings. That's all you need use the database.

Constraints follow from the given statements and possible situations that can arise. You declare them to prevent states that can't arise.

There's an "inclusion dependency" constraint when some source columns' value set must be a subset of a target columns' value set. If the target also has to form a key of its table then there's a "foreign key" constraint. Whether the target table is the source table doesn't matter. In SQL there is a kind of declaration with the syntax "foreign key" but because its target just has to be unique not a key it actually only defines a foreign superkey. Certain design methods happen to focus on certain constraints at the expense of others and even the table meanings.

You have in mind some relationship (not necessarily embodied an a table)

```
coupled(p,q) // == '[p] & [q] are coupled'
    key {p,q}
    // plus CHECK-expressible constraints only involving coupled
```

Embedding this table in another just means those constraints would apply to the appropriate part of the embedding table.

You also have in mind (not necessarily embodied in a table)

```
userfact(p,...) // == '...[p] is such that ...'
    key {p}
```

If you declare

```
userbig(p,...,q) // == userfact(p,...) and coupled(p,q)
    key {p} fk q->p
    // plus coupled-like constraints involving select p,q from userbig
```

then you can't record userfact(p,...) about p who are not coupled. Plus you have to involve the above select to query about coupling independent of user facts.

If you let q be null then you get

```
usernull(p,...,q) // == userfact(p,...) and (q is null and not exists q coupled(p,q) or not q is null and coupled(p,q))
    key {p}
    // plus coupled-like constraints involving select p,q from usernull where not q is null
```

Unfortunately, now you have to involve the even more complicated select above to query about coupling independent of user facts. Also, the constraint that corresponds to fk q->p is no longer a fk constraint but more complex, since q can be null. Also, any time you want any part (even all) of usernull you might have to test for q's nullness to make sure that the rows that you want are used.

Worst, SQL operators behave complexly because of its sort-of-3VL so the meanings of all but extremely simple queries involving nulls are extremely complex. They aren't the otherwise simple combinations of tables' meanings. Nulls should be avoided.

So what you really want is just `userfact` and `coupled` with its `fk p->userfact.p, q->userfact.p`.

Industrially with present SQL DBMSs, one must constantly choose for performance to constrain non-declaratively and to use nulls in some tables (with nulls removed as close to query expression leaves as possible). But first one should design properly.