# Is merging two tables that inherit from the same class a bad idea?

Tags: inheritance, database-design, anti-patterns

Say I have an entity, Alpha and two other entities A1 and A2 that both inherit from Alpha. Certain constraints sort of force me to merge the two tables into one. But I feel that this is not a very good (or even terrible) idea (I'm even thinking anti-pattern). Problem is that apart from the huge size (many columns) that the table might end up having, I don't see any other obvious problems. Can someone please point them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common situation that can be put into tables various ways. Taking Alpha, A1 and A2 to be entity types, the most straightforward is:

```
A1(a,....) fk references Alpha // a is of type A1 and ...
A2(a,....) fk references Alpha // a is of type A2 and ...
Alpha(a,...) // a is of type Alpha and ....
```

(There may be constraints check A1(p,...) implies not A2(p,...) and/or A2(p,...) implies not A1(p,...).)

Alpha is the type of things that are either of type A1 or A2 or maybe something else. ("Inherit from Alpha" doesn't make that clear.) Tables A1 & A2 have columns unique to each; Alpha, shared columns.

The topic is subtypes and supertypes with tables. Read about it.

EDIT

The problem with nulls is that any time you want to query about entities of the above three types, you have extract these tables anyway, and unless nulls are removed near the leaves of a query expression they quickly lead to unmanageably complex and unintuitive query meanings. See [this example of how nulls complicate table meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23821103/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

If A1 has columns that A2 doesn't have, or vice versa (which seems likely) you'll end up with lots of NULLs in your table.

Most importantly, though, it seems to me that A1 and A2 are *logically different* types, (even though they have a common part Alpha), so they should be in different tables.

It would be better to create a view that combined the tables into one, while keeping them logically separated.

Comment: Ok, so is this the only problem (a lot of NULLs) or is there something else?

Comment: I would argue having two types in one table would be the bigger problem, even if it's not immediately apparent how that can cause concrete issues. It's hard for me to come up with any concrete issues without knowing any details about your types.